# Reversing Polarity on Switch Mode PSU to use on Audio Equipment

Tags: reverse-polarity

I have a normal 12v 1amp switch mode psu. with positive pin, negative sleeve. I want to use it on a Roland ex3 s keyboard, which I got as a gift, but no power supply.  The PSU specs match those of the Roland according to the manual.
Is it save to change the polarity of the PSU, and use it?
Do you get specially adapted switch mode psu with negative pin positive sleeve?
Much Appreciated
Johann

Answer (score 1):

Other than being evil, there's nothing special about PSUs with centre-negative barrel jack. As long as the specs match, you can safely swap the polarity on a centre-positive PSU and use it with you keyboard.